# maven: run idlj command before compiling code

Tags: java, maven, corba, idl

I am working on a CORBA project using maven build. Before maven starts compilation, the idl needs to be processed to generate some java source files. I have tried the idlj-maven-plugin but it doesn't allow me to override "-fallTIE" argument. So what other ways run idlj compiler command from maven before maven starts the compilation phase?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to find some hints on the internet on the way to do this using the exec-maven-plugin. Here is the plugin configuration you have to add in the project's pom.xml

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-idl</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>idlj</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>-fall -td ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/idl src/main/idl/HelloWorld.idl</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```